# can we use Applescript in mac development

Tags: macos, applescript

current I am using some applescripts to the commands in mac machine.is apple allow applescripts in reviewing process or I have to look on alternatives but applescripts is working fine as for my requiremnts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187426/can-i-know-how-to-detect-the-screen-sharing-is-running-or-not-in-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.** Apple allows `AppleScript` in the Mac OS app development. You just need to add `sandboxing` in side your project and list all the app for you are using in AppleScript inside your apps `entitlements` file.

If you not added any `entitlements` then it will not allowed by apple. Try your app in sandboxing mode and you can see `AppleScript` not working because of no `entitlements` added for app.
**Note : Some of the app not allowed to access using `AppleScript`. You app will be rejected by apple review team**

To use `AppleScript`:

1. `ON` App sandbox in project.
2. Add all `entitlements` required for `AppleScript` access.

Answer (score 0):

***(Only If you wish to deploy through Mac App Store)***

Few things before starting your work I suggests that you should go through this links in order to be sure that after your hard work you get want to want.

[Determine Whether Your App Is Suitable for Sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html)

[Enabling App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW5)

[App Sandbox Temporary Exception Entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW1)

1. Apple script doesn't work in Sandbox (As far as I know)
2. Your app should have a temporary exception (Doc mentions it)

**Determine Whether Your App Is Suitable for Sandboxing**

> Sending Apple events to arbitrary apps With App Sandbox, you can
>   receive Apple events and respond to Apple events, but you cannot send
>   Apple events to arbitrary apps.
>
> However, for applications that specifically provide scripting access
>   groups, you can send appropriate Apple events to those apps if your
>   app includes a scripting targets entitlement.
>
> For other applications, by using a temporary exception entitlement,
>   you can enable the sending of Apple events to a list of specific apps
>   that you specify, as described in Entitlement Key Reference.
>
> Finally, your app can use the subclasses of NSUserScriptTask class to
>   run user-provided AppleScript scripts out of a special directory,
>   NSApplicationScriptsDirectory (~/Library/Application
>   Scripts/code-signing-identifier/). Although your app can read files
>   within this directory, it cannot write files into this directory; the
>   user must manually place scripts here. For details, see the
>   documentation for NSUserScriptTask and WWDC 2012: Secure Automation
>   Techniques in OS X.

**A complimentary**

[A Strategy for UI Scripting in AppleScript](https://n8henrie.com/2013/03/a-strategy-for-ui-scripting-in-applescript/#comment-2324286651)

[Scripting from a Sandbox](https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/)